# "running python rtupdate hooks for python3.5" failing

Tags: apt, python, dpkg, dependencies

I reinstalled Ubuntu avec some file system problems. Now I get this:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fingerprint/fprint/ubuntu xenial InRelease  
Hit:3 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease                                   
Hit:4 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease                                 
Hit:5 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-proposed InRelease
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages [192 kB]
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main i386 Packages [186 kB]
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 Packages [65.6 kB]
Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe i386 Packages [63.4 kB]
Fetched 609 kB in 3s (201 kB/s)                          
Reading package lists... Done
```

So no problem so far I think. Then:

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
11 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up python3 (3.5.1-3) ...
running python rtupdate hooks for python3.5...
dpkg-query: package 'onboard' is not installed
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of onboard
error running python rtupdate hook onboard
dpkg-query: package 'python3-uno' is not installed
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of python3-uno
error running python rtupdate hook python3-uno
dpkg-query: package 'rhythmbox-plugins' is not installed
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of rhythmbox-plugins
error running python rtupdate hook rhythmbox-plugins
dpkg-query: package 'rhythmbox' is not installed
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of rhythmbox
error running python rtupdate hook rhythmbox
dpkg-query: package 'totem-plugins' is not installed
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of totem-plugins
error running python rtupdate hook totem-plugins
dpkg-query: package 'ubuntu-drivers-common' is not installed
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of ubuntu-drivers-common
error running python rtupdate hook ubuntu-drivers-common
dpkg: error processing package python3 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 4
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-gi:
 python3-gi depends on python3 (<< 3.6); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-gi depends on python3 (>= 3.5~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-gi (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gir1.2-ibus-1.0:amd64:
 gir1.2-ibus-1.0:amd64 depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gir1.2-ibus-1.0:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of hplip-data:
 hplip-data depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package hplip-data (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ibus:
 ibus depends on gir1.2-ibus-1.0 (= 1.5.11-1ubuntu2); however:
  Package gir1.2-ibus-1.0:amd64 is not configured yet.
 ibus depends on python3-gi; however:
  Package python3-gi is not configured yet.
 ibus depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ibus (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ibus-table:
 ibus-table depends on ibus (>= 1.5.0); however:
  Package ibus is not configured yet.
 ibus-table depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ibus-table (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-dev:
 python3-dev depends on python3 (= 3.5.1-3); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-pip:
 python3-pip depends on python3:any (>= 3.4~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-pip (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-pkg-resources:
 python3-pkg-resources depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-pkg-resources (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-setuptools:
 python3-setuptools depends on python3-pkg-resources (= 20.7.0-1); however:
  Package python3-pkg-resources is not configured yet.
 python3-setuptools depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-setuptools (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-wheel:
 python3-wheel depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-wheel (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3
 python3-gi
 gir1.2-ibus-1.0:amd64
 hplip-data
 ibus
 ibus-table
 python3-dev
 python3-pip
 python3-pkg-resources
 python3-setuptools
 python3-wheel
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post English output instead. You can change the output language of a terminal command temporarily by writing `LANG=C` in front of it, like `LANG=C sudo apt-get update`. If you run `LANG=C` as single separate command, it will change the language of your current shell session (everything inside the current open terminal window only, until you close it) to English. Thanks for helping us to help you :)

Comment: Ok, I'm doing it right now. I didn't know that, thank you

Answer (score 22):

I was getting the

```
dpkg: error processing package python3 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 4
```

with similar output all around due to having rtupdate hooks for packages that were not installed on the system in `/usr/share/python3/runtime.d`.

Fixed by removing the `<missing-package-name>.rtupdate` files in the directory above and reinstalling python3.

Comment: Just reinstalling the system python3 worked for me. Though it was quite a pain.

Comment: I completely cleared the runtime.d directory of all .rtupdate files and got passed the issue.

Answer (score -2):

in your case you have just to execute:

```
sudo apt-get --fix-broken install
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install onboard -y
```

*-By NacreousDawn596, answering questions just for fun.*

Comment: bruh, I said in his case "dpkg-query: package 'onboard' is not installed", not in everyone cases lmao