# How we fix dependency problem and python3 broken problem in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: python3

```
/home/bicky# apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libcryptsetup12 libdevmapper1.02.1 libidn11 libip4tc0 libjson-c3 libkmod2
  libmpdec2 libpython3-stdlib libpython3.6-minimal libpython3.6-stdlib python3
  python3-minimal python3.6 python3.6-minimal systemd
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be upgraded:
  bsdutils fdisk libblkid1 libfdisk1 libmount1 libsmartcols1 libuuid1 mount
  util-linux uuid-runtime
10 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 1,739 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libuuid1 amd64 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.2 [20.0 kB]
Get:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libblkid1 amd64 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.2 [124 kB]
Get:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libmount1 amd64 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.2 [136 kB]
Get:4 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libfdisk1 amd64 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.2 [164 kB]
Get:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libsmartcols1 amd64 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.2 [83.6 kB]
Get:6 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 fdisk amd64 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.2 [107 kB]
Get:7 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 util-linux amd64 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.2 [902 kB]
Get:8 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 mount amd64 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.2 [106 kB]
Get:9 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 bsdutils amd64 1:2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.2 [60.3 kB]
Get:10 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 uuid-runtime amd64 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.2 [34.8 kB]
Fetched 1,739 kB in 5s (374 kB/s)   
(Reading database ... 26124 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libuuid1_2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libuuid1:amd64 (2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.2) over (2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.1) ...
Setting up libuuid1:amd64 (2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.2) ...
(Reading database ... 26124 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libblkid1_2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libblkid1:amd64 (2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.2) over (2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.1) ...
Setting up libblkid1:amd64 (2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.2) ...
(Reading database ... 26124 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libmount1_2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libmount1:amd64 (2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.2) over (2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.1) ...
Setting up libmount1:amd64 (2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.2) ...
(Reading database ... 26124 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libfdisk1_2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libfdisk1:amd64 (2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.2) over (2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.1) ...
Setting up libfdisk1:amd64 (2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.2) ...
(Reading database ... 26124 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libsmartcols1_2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libsmartcols1:amd64 (2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.2) over (2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.1) ...
Setting up libsmartcols1:amd64 (2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.2) ...
(Reading database ... 26124 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../fdisk_2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking fdisk (2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.2) over (2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.1) ...
Setting up fdisk (2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.2) ...
(Reading database ... 26124 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../util-linux_2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking util-linux (2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.2) over (2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.1) ...
Setting up util-linux (2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.2) ...
(Reading database ... 26124 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mount_2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mount (2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.2) over (2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../bsdutils_1%3a2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking bsdutils (1:2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.2) over (1:2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.1) ...
Setting up bsdutils (1:2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.2) ...
(Reading database ... 26124 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../uuid-runtime_2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking uuid-runtime (2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.2) over (2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Setting up python3 (3.6.5-3ubuntu1) ...
running python rtupdate hooks for python3.6...
dpkg-query: package 'dh-python' is not installed
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of dh-python
error running python rtupdate hook dh-python
dpkg-query: package 'gdebi-core' is not installed
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of gdebi-core
error running python rtupdate hook gdebi-core
dpkg-query: package 'gedit' is not installed
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of gedit
error running python rtupdate hook gedit
dpkg-query: package 'hplip-data' is not installed
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of hplip-data
error running python rtupdate hook hplip-data
dpkg-query: package 'ibus-table' is not installed
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of ibus-table
error running python rtupdate hook ibus-table
dpkg-query: package 'ibus' is not installed
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of ibus
error running python rtupdate hook ibus
dpkg-query: package 'python3-uno' is not installed
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of python3-uno
error running python rtupdate hook python3-uno
dpkg-query: package 'rhythmbox-plugin-alternative-toolbar' is not installed
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of rhythmbox-plugin-alternative-toolbar
error running python rtupdate hook rhythmbox-plugin-alternative-toolbar
dpkg-query: package 'rhythmbox-plugins' is not installed
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of rhythmbox-plugins
error running python rtupdate hook rhythmbox-plugins
dpkg-query: package 'system-config-printer-common' is not installed
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of system-config-printer-common
error running python rtupdate hook system-config-printer-common
dpkg-query: package 'system-config-printer' is not installed
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of system-config-printer
error running python rtupdate hook system-config-printer
dpkg-query: package 'ubuntu-drivers-common' is not installed
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of ubuntu-drivers-common
error running python rtupdate hook ubuntu-drivers-common
dpkg-query: package 'virtualbox' is not installed
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of virtualbox
error running python rtupdate hook virtualbox
dpkg: error processing package python3 (--configure):
 installed python3 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 4
Setting up mount (2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.2) ...
Setting up uuid-runtime (2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.2) ...
Setting up systemd (237-3ubuntu10.3) ...
cp: '/etc/resolv.conf' and '/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf' are the same file
dpkg: error processing package systemd (--configure):
 installed systemd package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3
 systemd
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@bicky-H81M-S:/home/bicky# sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up python3 (3.6.5-3ubuntu1) ...
running python rtupdate hooks for python3.6...
dpkg-query: package 'dh-python' is not installed
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of dh-python
error running python rtupdate hook dh-python
dpkg-query: package 'gdebi-core' is not installed
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of gdebi-core
error running python rtupdate hook gdebi-core
dpkg-query: package 'gedit' is not installed
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of gedit
error running python rtupdate hook gedit
dpkg-query: package 'hplip-data' is not installed
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of hplip-data
error running python rtupdate hook hplip-data
dpkg-query: package 'ibus-table' is not installed
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of ibus-table
error running python rtupdate hook ibus-table
dpkg-query: package 'ibus' is not installed
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of ibus
error running python rtupdate hook ibus
dpkg-query: package 'python3-uno' is not installed
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of python3-uno
error running python rtupdate hook python3-uno
dpkg-query: package 'rhythmbox-plugin-alternative-toolbar' is not installed
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of rhythmbox-plugin-alternative-toolbar
error running python rtupdate hook rhythmbox-plugin-alternative-toolbar
dpkg-query: package 'rhythmbox-plugins' is not installed
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of rhythmbox-plugins
error running python rtupdate hook rhythmbox-plugins
dpkg-query: package 'system-config-printer-common' is not installed
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of system-config-printer-common
error running python rtupdate hook system-config-printer-common
dpkg-query: package 'system-config-printer' is not installed
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of system-config-printer
error running python rtupdate hook system-config-printer
dpkg-query: package 'ubuntu-drivers-common' is not installed
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of ubuntu-drivers-common
error running python rtupdate hook ubuntu-drivers-common
dpkg-query: package 'virtualbox' is not installed
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of virtualbox
error running python rtupdate hook virtualbox
dpkg: error processing package python3 (--configure):
 installed python3 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 4
Setting up systemd (237-3ubuntu10.3) ...
cp: '/etc/resolv.conf' and '/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf' are the same file
dpkg: error processing package systemd (--configure):
 installed systemd package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3
 systemd
```

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/1266423/cannot-install-any-packages-because-of-python; https://askubuntu.com/questions/862367/running-python-rtupdate-hooks-for-python3-5-failing/941789

Comment: Same problem occurs while I use any installation related command

Comment: Have you tried the solutions I linked? If not, please [edit] your question to include the output you get when trying them.

Comment: `python3` and `systemd` are not fully installed. Hence the problem. Try `sudo apt-get install -f`. Report back to @heynnema

Answer (score 0):

The following commands help me solve the issue:

```
rm -rf /usr/share/python3/runtime.d/*
rm -rf /usr/lib/valgrind/*
apt-get -f install
```

Comment: AFAIK valgrind is related to C/C++ and not python!!