# Can't install packages using apt

Tags: apt, software-installation, upgrade, python3

I am not able to install a package using `apt` due to the following error:

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
134 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up python3 (3.8.2-0ubuntu2) ...
running python rtupdate hooks for python3.8...
dpkg-query: package 'rhythmbox-plugin-alternative-toolbar' is not installed
Use dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list archive files contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of rhythmbox-plugin-alternative-toolbar
error running python rtupdate hook rhythmbox-plugin-alternative-toolbar
dpkg-query: package 'rhythmbox-plugins' is not installed
Use dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list archive files contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of rhythmbox-plugins
error running python rtupdate hook rhythmbox-plugins
dpkg-query: package 'ubuntu-drivers-common' is not installed
Use dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list archive files contents.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of ubuntu-drivers-common
error running python rtupdate hook ubuntu-drivers-common
dpkg: error processing package python3 (--configure):
 installed python3 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 4
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apport:
 apport depends on python3; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package apport (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-tz:
 python3-tz depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-tz (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-apport:
 python3-apport depends on python3:any (>= 3.0~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-apport (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-cupshelpers:
 python3-cupshelpers depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-cupshelpers (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-requests-unixsocket:
 python3-requests-unixsocket depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-requests-unixsocket (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-six:
 python3-six depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-six (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-simplejson:
 python3-simplejson depends on python3 (<< 3.9); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-simplejson depends on python3 (>= 3.8~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-simplejson depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-simplejson (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ibus-table:
 ibus-table depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ibus-table (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-cups:
 python3-cups depends on python3 (<< 3.9); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-cups depends on python3 (>= 3.8~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-cups (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-oauthlib:
 python3-oauthlib depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-oauthlib (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-chardet:
 python3-chardet depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-chardet (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-secretstorage:
 python3-secretstorage depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-secretstorage (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of system-config-printer:
 system-config-printer depends on python3-cups (>= 1.9.60); however:
  Package python3-cups is not configured yet.
 system-config-printer depends on python3-cupshelpers (= 1.5.12-0ubuntu1); however:
  Package python3-cupshelpers is not configured yet.
 system-config-printer depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package system-config-printer (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-certifi:
 python3-certifi depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-certifi (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-cryptography:
 python3-cryptography depends on python3 (>= 3~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-cryptography depends on python3-six (>= 1.4.1); however:
  Package python3-six is not configured yet.
 python3-cryptography depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-cryptography (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-wadllib:
 python3-wadllib depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-wadllib (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-debian:
 python3-debian depends on python3-chardet; however:
  Package python3-chardet is not configured yet.
 python3-debian depends on python3-six (>> 1.4~); however:
  Package python3-six is not configured yet.
 python3-debian depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-debian (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-gi:
 python3-gi depends on python3 (<< 3.9); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-gi depends on python3 (>= 3.8~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-gi depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-gi (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-requests:
 python3-requests depends on python3-certifi; however:
  Package python3-certifi is not configured yet.
 python3-requests depends on python3-chardet (<< 3.1.0); however:
  Package python3-chardet is not configured yet.
 python3-requests depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-requests depends on python3-chardet (>= 3.0.2); however:
  Package python3-chardet is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-requests (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-idna:
 python3-idna depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-idna (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-urllib3:
 python3-urllib3 depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-urllib3 depends on python3-six; however:
  Package python3-six is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-urllib3 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-shell:
 gnome-shell depends on python3; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gnome-shell (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-session:
 ubuntu-session depends on gnome-shell (>= 3.36.0-2ubuntu1~); however:
  Package gnome-shell is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-session (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ibus:
 ibus depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 ibus depends on python3-gi; however:
  Package python3-gi is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ibus (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gdm3:
 gdm3 depends on gnome-shell (>= 3.19.92); however:
  Package gnome-shell is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gdm3 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-defer:
 python3-defer depends on python3:any (>= 3.2~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-defer (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-keyring:
 python3-keyring depends on python3-secretstorage; however:
  Package python3-secretstorage is not configured yet.
 python3-keyring depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-keyring (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-httplib2:
 python3-httplib2 depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-httplib2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of language-selector-common:
 language-selector-common depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package language-selector-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of lsb-release:
 lsb-release depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package lsb-release (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-protobuf:
 python3-protobuf depends on python3 (<< 3.9); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-protobuf depends on python3 (>= 3.8~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-protobuf depends on python3-six (>= 1.9); however:
  Package python3-six is not configured yet.
 python3-protobuf depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-protobuf (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-rfc3339:
 python3-rfc3339 depends on python3-tz; however:
  Package python3-tz is not configured yet.
 python3-rfc3339 depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-rfc3339 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-macaroonbakery:
 python3-macaroonbakery depends on python3-protobuf (>= 3.0.0); however:
  Package python3-protobuf is not configured yet.
 python3-macaroonbakery depends on python3-requests (>= 2.18.1); however:
  Package python3-requests is not configured yet.
 python3-macaroonbakery depends on python3-rfc3339 (>= 1.0); however:
  Package python3-rfc3339 is not configured yet.
 python3-macaroonbakery depends on python3-six (<< 2.0); however:
  Package python3-six is not configured yet.
 python3-macaroonbakery depends on python3-six (>= 1.11.0); however:
  Package python3-six is not configured yet.
 python3-macaroonbakery depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-macaroonbakery (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets:
 python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets depends on python3:any (>= 3.2~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets depends on python3-gi; however:
  Package python3-gi is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-ibus-1.0:
 python3-ibus-1.0 depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-ibus-1.0 depends on python3-gi (>= 3.8); however:
  Package python3-gi is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-ibus-1.0 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-lazr.restfulclient:
 python3-lazr.restfulclient depends on python3-httplib2 (>= 0.7.7); however:
  Package python3-httplib2 is not configured yet.
 python3-lazr.restfulclient depends on python3-simplejson; however:
  Package python3-simplejson is not configured yet.
 python3-lazr.restfulclient depends on python3-wadllib (>= 1.1.4); however:
  Package python3-wadllib is not configured yet.
 python3-lazr.restfulclient depends on python3-oauthlib; however:
  Package python3-oauthlib is not configured yet.
 python3-lazr.restfulclient depends on python3-six; however:
  Package python3-six is not configured yet.
 python3-lazr.restfulclient depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-lazr.restfulclient (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-gi-cairo:
 python3-gi-cairo depends on python3-gi (= 3.36.0-1); however:
  Package python3-gi is not configured yet.
 python3-gi-cairo depends on python3 (<< 3.9); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-gi-cairo depends on python3 (>= 3.8~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-gi-cairo (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-nacl:
 python3-nacl depends on python3 (>= 3~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-nacl depends on python3-six; however:
  Package python3-six is not configured yet.
 python3-nacl depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-nacl (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-systemd:
 python3-systemd depends on python3 (<< 3.9); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-systemd depends on python3 (>= 3.8~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-systemd depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-systemd (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-cffi-backend:
 python3-cffi-backend depends on python3 (<< 3.9); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-cffi-backend depends on python3 (>= 3.8~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-cffi-backend (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of zoom:
 zoom depends on ibus; however:
  Package ibus is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package zoom (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-blinker:
 python3-blinker depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-blinker (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-pkg-resources:
 python3-pkg-resources depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-pkg-resources (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-entrypoints:
 python3-entrypoints depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-entrypoints (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of networkd-dispatcher:
 networkd-dispatcher depends on python3-gi; however:
  Package python3-gi is not configured yet.
 networkd-dispatcher depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package networkd-dispatcher (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of language-selector-gnome:
 language-selector-gnome depends on language-selector-common (= 0.204); however:
  Package language-selector-common is not configured yet.
 language-selector-gnome depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 language-selector-gnome depends on python3-gi; however:
  Package python3-gi is not configured yet.
 language-selector-gnome depends on python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets; however:
  Package python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package language-selector-gnome (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gedit-common:
 gedit-common depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gedit-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-dbus:
 python3-dbus depends on python3 (<< 3.9); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-dbus depends on python3 (>= 3.8~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-dbus depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-dbus (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of system-config-printer-common:
 system-config-printer-common depends on python3-cups (>= 1.9.60); however:
  Package python3-cups is not configured yet.
 system-config-printer-common depends on python3-cupshelpers (= 1.5.12-0ubuntu1); however:
  Package python3-cupshelpers is not configured yet.
 system-config-printer-common depends on python3-dbus; however:
  Package python3-dbus is not configured yet.
 system-config-printer-common depends on python3-gi; however:
  Package python3-gi is not configured yet.
 system-config-printer-common depends on python3-requests; however:
  Package python3-requests is not configured yet.
 system-config-printer-common depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package system-config-printer-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3
 apport
 python3-tz
 python3-apport
 python3-cupshelpers
 python3-requests-unixsocket
 python3-six
 python3-simplejson
 ibus-table
 python3-cups
 python3-oauthlib
 python3-chardet
 python3-secretstorage
 system-config-printer
 python3-certifi
 python3-cryptography
 python3-wadllib
 python3-debian
 python3-gi
 python3-requests
 python3-idna
 python3-urllib3
 gnome-shell
 ubuntu-session
 ibus
 gdm3
 python3-defer
 python3-keyring
 python3-httplib2
 language-selector-common
 lsb-release
 python3-protobuf
 python3-rfc3339
 python3-macaroonbakery
 python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets
 python3-ibus-1.0
 python3-lazr.restfulclient
 python3-gi-cairo
 python3-nacl
 python3-systemd
 python3-cffi-backend
 zoom
 python3-blinker
 python3-pkg-resources
 python3-entrypoints
 networkd-dispatcher
 language-selector-gnome
 gedit-common
 python3-dbus
 system-config-printer-common
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
```

So I tried to fix the issue by running:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

But the same error happened.

I upgraded my Ubuntu from 19.10 to 20.04. And Suddenly Ubuntu lost the database of `apt` packages and didn't recognize the packages that are already installed.

Does anyone face the same issue and have a solution to this?

Many thanks!

Comment: this may help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/862367/running-python-rtupdate-hooks-for-python3-5-failing/941789 or https://askubuntu.com/questions/1137654/debian-apt-install-broken-after-deleting-python

Comment: @pLumo Hey thank you for the reference. it did work for me. Can you add it as an answer, not comment, so that I can accept it as an answer?

Comment: Which one helped? We will link as duplicate then, that is better :-)

Comment: This one - https://askubuntu.com/questions/862367/running-python-rtupdate-hooks-for-python3-5-failing/941789

Comment: Yeah, there is only one answer to the question and it did solve my issue.